# WordPress Filter Escape Problem

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to replace some text in a WordPress post with the help of WordPress Filter (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-filter/) but but all ' and " are get escaped. What should I do to prevent it from escaping?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an escape character in front of them.  Try using a "\" in front of the character you want to escape.